# How do I get a list of users in AD who have the ability to reset another user's password?

Tags: active-directory, permissions, delegation

I need to provide a list of all the users who can reset other users' passwords. e.g. Service Desk Staff, Domain Admins etc.

This might have been delegated at a specific OU or at domain level. Is there a way to query AD to output ALL users who have this facility at ANY level of the OU structure?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write your own script to query each OU for all groups/users who have this permissions.  Here are a couple articles to get you started:

1. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753491.aspx
2. http://www.indented.co.uk/index.php/2009/10/02/get-dsacl/